# Calculate percentage wise stats using C sharp?

Tags: c#

i want to find the stats that will calculate percentage and give results in following format :
 WX GSA search % = GSA occurrences / GSA occurrences + Search occurrences + ADVSearch occurrences * 100 i.e. in this case it should give like :  3 / 3 + 2 + 2 * 100 = 42.8

I have tried code that will give occurrences of every search :

My code is here :

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\sample log.txt");
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX Search"));   // WX Rule Based Search.
        Console.WriteLine(TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX GSA Search"));  // WX GSA Search.
        Console.WriteLine(TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX ADVSearch"));   //WX Form Based Search.
        // keep screen from going away
        // when run from VS.NET
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public static class TextTool
{
    public static int CountStringOccurrences(string text, string pattern)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
        {
            i += pattern.Length;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have logs in following format :   WX GSA Search = Server: yukon.corp.wx.com 
 WX GSA Search = Server: yukon.corp.wx.com 
 WX GSA Search = Server: yukon.corp.wx.com WX Search = Server:yukon.corp.wx.com 
 WX Search = Server:yukon.corp.wx.comWX ADVSearch = Server:yukon.corp.wx.com
 WX ADVSearch = Server:yukon.corp.wx.com

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Also, edit additional info into your question instead of adding it as comments

Comment: i want to find the stats that will calculate %age and give results in following format :

 WX GSA search % = GSA occurrences / GSA occurrences + Search occurrences + ADVSearch occurrences * 100 i.e. in this case it should give like :  3 / 3 + 2 + 2 * 100 = 42.8

Comment: i am able to capture occurrences of  searches as you can see in the code.

Comment: But what you can't do? What is your question?

Comment: On a side note: Multiplication binds stronger than addition, thus your formula is essentially `1 + Search occurences + (100 * ADVSearch occurences)`, which would evaluate to `203` in your example

Comment: @ Adil : i want to calculate % for GSA by using formula : GSA Search/GSA Search+Search+ADV Search * 100 . i have achieved stats to find their occurrences, now i want % wise stats of every search type (GSA search, Search, ADV search).

Comment: Did you see my answer? Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand the question. Do you just mean to calculate the formula and show it on console screen? If you mean this here is the code you need:

```
static void Main()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\sample log.txt");
    string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
    int wxSearchCount = TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX Search");   // WX Rule Based Search.
    int wxGsaSearchCount = TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX GSA Search");  // WX GSA Search.
    int wxAdvSearchCount = TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(myString, "WX ADVSearch");   //WX Form Based Search.

            double result = Convert.ToDouble(wxGsaSearchCount * 100) / Convert.ToDouble((wxGsaSearchCount + wxSearchCount + wxAdvSearchCount));

            Console.WriteLine("WX Search: {0}\nWX GSA Search: {1}\nWX ADVSearch: {2}\nResult: {3}",
                                wxSearchCount, wxGsaSearchCount, wxAdvSearchCount, result.ToString("0.00"));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Sir this code does the same thing which i already shared with you. Now we have got all the stats of searches, i want to find out % wise stats. e.g for GSA search % stats can be like = Gsa search / Gsa search + search + ADV search and their ratio * 100

Comment: I think it does what you need: double result = wxGsaSearchCount / (wxGsaSearchCount + wxSearchCount + wxAdvSearchCount) * 100. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: yes , you are right. But here is one fight when i print "result", console window displays 0 , but when i print "wxGsaSearchCount", it gives appropriate value. Is something wrong here with line : double result = wxGsaSearchCount / (wxGsaSearchCount + wxSearchCount + wxAdvSearchCount) * 100;

Comment: double result = (WXAdvSearchCount * 100 / (WXGsaSearchCount + WXSearchCount + WXAdvSearchCount));

Answer (score 0):

You can format strings in .NET using the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1dzhdx.aspx) method.

```
int score = 50;
string formattedString = String.Format("My Score : {0}", score);
Console.WriteLine(formattedString); 
//My Score : 50
```

Comment: have you seen my logs ? also i mentioned the formula that needs to be implemented in the code.

Comment: Please read the String.Format docs on the link, we will gladly help you if you are still not sure about what to do after reading it.